# Crear Primary Key SQL Server en Tabla existente

Tags: sql, sql-server

Deseo insertar una nueva columna al principio antes de `(userName)`, con una llave primaria unica e incrementable por defecto:
he intentado esto pero no me funciona:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE ;
```

Answer (score 2):

No estas asignando la PK a ninguna columna de la tabla.
Tampoco puedo saber si dicha columna ya existe, o la estas creando.

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD CONSTRAINT PK_id PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

---

Suponiendo que dicha columna no existe, y además deben existir valores dentro.
Puedes hacer esto:

```
//Primero, crear la columna
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD id int identity(1,1) NOT NULL 

//Luego agregar la PK
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD CONSTRAINT PK_id PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

Comment: No, no existe la columna, deseo crearla nueva, antes de la columna `userName`

Comment: Ahi agregué un detalle que puedes probar. De todos modos, da igual en donde este la columna. Podrías buscar eso a parte si es que en realidad te molesta, se que al menos MySQL te deja reordenar, pero desconozco si SLQ SERVER lo permite